# Read all worksheets in an Excel workbook into an R list with data.frames

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I understand that `XLConnect` can be used to read an Excel worksheet into R. For example, this would read the first worksheet in a workbook called `test.xls` into R.

```
library(XLConnect)
readWorksheetFromFile('test.xls', sheet = 1)
```

I have an Excel Workbook with multiple worksheets.

How can all worksheets in a workbook be imported into a list in R where each element of the list is a data.frame for a given sheet, and where the name of each element corresponds to the name of the worksheet in Excel?

Comment: apart from `xlconnect` and `readxl`, package `xlsx` permits to manipulate excel files in `R` (all sheets or just some)

Comment: Very good tutorial: https://dominicroye.github.io/en/2019/import-excel-sheets-with-r/

Answer (score 159):

#### Updated answer using readxl (22nd June 2015)

Since posting this question the `readxl` package has been released. It supports both `xls` and `xlsx` format. Importantly, in contrast to other excel import packages, it works on Windows, Mac, and Linux without requiring installation of additional software.

So a function for importing all sheets in an Excel workbook would be:

```
library(readxl)    
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename, tibble = FALSE) {
    # I prefer straight data.frames
    # but if you like tidyverse tibbles (the default with read_excel)
    # then just pass tibble = TRUE
    sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
    x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
    if(!tibble) x <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)
    names(x) <- sheets
    x
}
```

This could be called with:

```
mysheets <- read_excel_allsheets("foo.xls")
```

#### Old Answer

Building on the answer provided by @mnel, here is a simple function that takes an Excel file as an argument and returns each sheet as a data.frame in a named list.

```
library(XLConnect)

importWorksheets <- function(filename) {
    # filename: name of Excel file
    workbook <- loadWorkbook(filename)
    sheet_names <- getSheets(workbook)
    names(sheet_names) <- sheet_names
    sheet_list <- lapply(sheet_names, function(.sheet){
        readWorksheet(object=workbook, .sheet)})
}
```

Thus, it could be called with:

```
importWorksheets('test.xls')
```

Comment: excellent, just learning that `readxl` has an `excel_sheets` method. wonderful.

Comment: What's the best way to add a filepath into this function?

Comment: @user7071759 if I understand you, then you should just be able to include path in `filename`. E.g., read_excel_allsheets("my/path/to/file/example.xls")

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked better than the others listed in this page.

Comment: It seems that this new answer gives me a a list within a list, and not a data frame within a list.

Comment: @Erosennin I'm not sure; it doesn't do that for me. I've added some code that removes the tibble class by default. Perhaps the tibble stuff was causing surprising results.

Comment: I am getting lists and not dataframes as well.

Comment: A simpler version of this function would be `lapply(excel_sheets(file.path), function(x) read_excel(file.path, x))`. If you prefer the non-tibble simply wrap read_excel in `as.data.frame()`. Names would have to be assigned after.

Comment: The tidyverse solution is more elegant [link](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/readxl-workflows.html#iterate-over-multiple-worksheets-in-a-workbook)

Comment: hi i tried to use your code but when using xlconnect i get error :> library("XLConnect")
Loading required package: XLConnectJars
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnectJars’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: package ‘XLConnectJars’ could not be loaded

Comment: I have made use of the function here on several occasions. It however has caused some issues when rbinding the resulting sheets as the readxl package seems to insert random blank rows which causes a bit of a headache. I altered your function to use the xlsx package which does not have this issue. `read_xlsx_allsheets <- function(filename) { 
  sheets <- openxlsx::getSheetNames(filename) 
  x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) openxlsx::read.xlsx(filename, sheet = X)) 
  names(x) <- sheets 
  x 
} `

Answer (score 46):

Note that most of XLConnect's functions are already vectorized. This means that you can read in all worksheets with one function call without having to do explicit vectorization:

```
require(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook(system.file("demoFiles/mtcars.xlsx", package = "XLConnect"))
lst = readWorksheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb))
```

With XLConnect 0.2-0 *lst* will already be a named list.

Comment: For me, this works 
`require(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("excel.xlsx")
lst = readWorksheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb))`

Comment: Me too. The solution answer did not work for me, could not locate the file even though it exists

Comment: The call with `system.file()` did Not work for me too.

Comment: instead using loadWorkbook(system.file("demoFiles/mtcars.xlsx", package = "XLConnect")), directly use loadWorkbook("demoFiles/mtcars.xlsx") to load workbook. It works.

Comment: This is the best answer for a password protected xlsx

Answer (score 42):

I stumbled across this old question and I think the easiest approach is still missing.

You can use `rio` to import all excel sheets with just one line of code.

```
library(rio)
data_list <- import_list("test.xls")
```

If you're a fan of the `tidyverse`, you can easily import them as tibbles by adding the `setclass` argument to the function call.

```
data_list <- import_list("test.xls", setclass = "tbl")
```

Suppose they have the same format, you could easily row bind them by setting the `rbind` argument to `TRUE`.

```
data_list <- import_list("test.xls", setclass = "tbl", rbind = TRUE)
```

Comment: `rio::import_list` is a great option. It can also import a subset of the sheets e.g. `import_list("test.xls", which = c(1, 2))` which can be really useful. I agree it's the easiest option here.

Answer (score 41):

From official `readxl` (tidyverse) documentation (changing first line):

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

path <- "data/datasets.xlsx"

path %>% 
  excel_sheets() %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(read_excel, path = path)
```

Details at:
http://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/readxl-workflows.html#iterate-over-multiple-worksheets-in-a-workbook

Comment: To keep sheet names, `df <- path %>% 
  excel_sheets() %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map_dfr(read_excel, path = path, .id = "SheetName")`

Comment: `excel_sheets()` does not exist

Answer (score 19):

Since this is the number one hit to the question: Read multi sheet excel to list:

here is the `openxlsx` solution:

```
filename <-"myFilePath"

sheets <- openxlsx::getSheetNames(filename)
SheetList <- lapply(sheets,openxlsx::read.xlsx,xlsxFile=filename)
names(SheetList) <- sheets
```

Answer (score 11):

Adding to Paul's answer. The sheets can also be concatenated using something like this:

```
data = path %>% 
excel_sheets() %>% 
set_names() %>% 
map_df(~ read_excel(path = path, sheet = .x), .id = "Sheet")
```

Libraries needed:

```
if(!require(pacman))install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load("tidyverse","readxl","purrr")
```

Comment: Good detail adding a new column using the sheetname!

Comment: I agree. A very good side effect of having a new column based on the sheetname.

Answer (score 8):

You can load the work book and then use `lapply`, `getSheets` and `readWorksheet` and do something like this.

```
wb.mtcars <- loadWorkbook(system.file("demoFiles/mtcars.xlsx", 
                          package = "XLConnect"))
sheet_names <- getSheets(wb.mtcars)
names(sheet_names) <- sheet_names

sheet_list <- lapply(sheet_names, function(.sheet){
    readWorksheet(object=wb.mtcars, .sheet)})
```

Comment: Nice one Martin!!

Answer (score 6):

To read multiple sheets from a workbook, use readxl package as follows:

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

final_dataFrame <- bind_rows(path_to_workbook %>%
                              excel_sheets() %>%
                              set_names() %>%
                              map(read_excel, path = path_to_workbook))
```

Here, bind_rows (`dplyr`) will put all data rows from all sheets
into one data frame, and `path_to_workbook` is the location of your data: "dir/of/the/data/workbook".

Answer (score 4):

Just for simplifying the very useful response of @Jeromy Anglim:

```
allsheets <- sapply(readxl::excel_sheets("your_file.xlsx"), simplify = F, USE.NAMES = T,
            function(X) readxl::read_excel("your_file.xlsx", sheet = X))
```

Answer (score 3):

[excel.link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/excel.link/index.html) will do the job.

I actually found it easier to use compared to XLConnect (not that either package is that difficult to use). Learning curve for both was about 5 minutes.

As an aside, you can easily find all R packages that mention the word "Excel" by browsing to
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above and had issues with the amount of data that my 20MB Excel I needed to convert consisted of; therefore the above did not work for me.

After more research I stumbled upon openxlsx and this one finally did the trick (and fast)
[Importing a big xlsx file into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147884/importing-a-big-xlsx-file-into-r)

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach based on the RDCOMClient :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

dir_Path <- "D:\\Dropbox\\Reponses_Stackoverflow\\stackoverflow_294\\"
excel_File <- "test_File.xlsx"
path_Excel_File <- paste0(dir_Path, excel_File)

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets() 
nb_Sheets <- Sheets$count() 

list_DF_By_Sheet <- list()

for(l in 1 : nb_Sheets)
{
  obj_Range <- Sheets[[l]]$Range("A:B")
  val <- obj_Range$value()
  nb_Val <- length(val)
  list_Vector <- list()
  
  for(i in 1 : nb_Val)
  {
    list_Vector[[i]] <- unlist(val[[i]])
  }
  
  df_Sheet <- do.call("cbind", list_Vector)
  list_DF_By_Sheet[[l]] <- df_Sheet
}

list_DF_By_Sheet
```