# Handling java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when writing to Excel from R

Tags: r, xlsx

The `xlsx` package can be used to read and write Excel spreadsheets from R.  Unfortunately, even for moderately large spreadsheets, `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` can occur.  In particular,

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  :
>     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>
> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "newInstance", .jfindClass(class),  :
>      java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

(Other related exceptions are also possible but rarer.)

A similar question was asked regarding this error when reading spreadsheets.

[Importing a big xlsx file into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19147884/134830)

The main advantage of using Excel spreadsheets as a data storage medium over CSV is that you can store multiple sheets in the same file, so here we consider a list of data frames to be written one data frame per worksheet.  This example dataset contains 40 data frames, each with two columns of up to 200k rows.  It is designed to be big enough to be problematic, but you can change the size by altering `n_sheets` and `n_rows`.

```
library(xlsx)
set.seed(19790801)
n_sheets <- 40
the_data <- replicate(
  n_sheets,
  {
    n_rows <- sample(2e5, 1)
    data.frame(
      x = runif(n_rows),
      y = sample(letters, n_rows, replace = TRUE)
    )
  },
  simplify = FALSE
)
names(the_data) <- paste("Sheet", seq_len(n_sheets))
```

The natural method of writing this to file is to create a workbook using [`createWorkbook`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xlsx/docs/createWorkbook), then loop over each data frame calling [`createSheet`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xlsx/docs/createSheet) and [`addDataFrame`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xlsx/docs/addDataFrame).  Finally the workbook can be written to file using [`saveWorkbook`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xlsx/docs/saveWorkbook).  I've added messages to the loop to make it easier to see where it falls over.

```
wb <- createWorkbook()  
for(i in seq_along(the_data))
{
  message("Creating sheet", i)
  sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = names(the_data)[i])
  message("Adding data frame", i)
  addDataFrame(the_data[[i]], sheet)
}
saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx")
```

Running this in 64-bit on a machine with 8GB RAM, it throws the `GC overhead limit exceeded` error while running `addDataFrame` for the first time.

How do I write large datasets to Excel spreadsheets using `xlsx`?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is a known issue:
http://code.google.com/p/rexcel/issues/detail?id=33

While unresolved, the issue page [links to a solution](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-xlsx-package-td3298470.html) by [Gabor Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck) suggesting that the heap size should be increased by setting the `java.parameters` option before the `rJava` package is loaded.  (`rJava` is a dependency of `xlsx`.)

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1000m")
```

The value `1000` is the number of megabytes of RAM to allow for the Java heap; it can be replaced with any value you like.  My experiments with this suggest that bigger values are better, and you can happily use your full RAM entitlement.  For example, I got the best results using:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8000m")
```

on the machine with 8GB RAM.

A further improvement can be obtained by requesting a garbage collection in each iteration of the loop.  As noted by @gjabel, R garbage collection can be performed using [`gc()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/gc). We can define a Java garbage collection function that calls the Java [`System.gc()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc()) method:

```
jgc <- function()
{
  .jcall("java/lang/System", method = "gc")
}
```

Then the loop can be updated to:

```
for(i in seq_along(the_data))
{
  gc()
  jgc()
  message("Creating sheet", i)
  sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = names(the_data)[i])
  message("Adding data frame", i)
  addDataFrame(the_data[[i]], sheet)
}
```

With both these code fixes, the code ran as far as `i = 29` before throwing an error.

One technique that I tried unsuccessfully was to use `write.xlsx2` to write the contents to file at each iteration.  This was slower than the other code, and it fell over on the 10th iteration (but at least part of the contents were written to file).

```
for(i in seq_along(the_data))
{
  message("Writing sheet", i)
  write.xlsx2(
    the_data[[i]], 
    "test.xlsx", 
    sheetName = names(the_data)[i], 
    append    = i > 1
  )
}
```

Comment: This whole problem can now be sidestepped by swapping the `xlsx` package for the `openxlsx` package, which is dependent upon `Rcpp` rather than Java.

Comment: `readxl` is another new C/C++ alternative that looks promising.

Comment: unfortunately I've found both of those are quite junk for detecting and reading dates--both end up in the incorrigible mess that is the Excel date format :\

Comment: @RichieCotton, nice alternative. However, openxlsx can not read .xls or .xlm files! (2007 excel file format).

Comment: call `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8000m")` before load `rJava`, `xlsxjars`, `xlsx` solved `Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Calls: getNetwork ... <Anonymous> -> .jrcall -> .jcall -> .jcheck -> .Call
Execution halted` in RHEL 6.3 x86_64, java 1.7.0_79 (Oracle), rJava_0.9-7, xlsxjars_0.6.0, xlsx_0.5.7

Comment: @RichieCotton also `openxlsx` and `readxl` don't have options for reading password protected .xlsx

Answer (score 8):

Building on @richie-cotton answer, I found adding `gc()` to the `jgc` function kept the CPU usage low.

```
jgc <- function()
{
  gc()
  .jcall("java/lang/System", method = "gc")
}
```

My previous `for` loop still struggled with the original `jgc` function, but with extra command, I no longer run into `GC overhead limit exceeded` error message.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for the above error:
Please use the below mentioned r - code:

```
detach(package:xlsx)
detach(package:XLConnect)
library(openxlsx)
```

And, try to import the file again and you will not get any error as it works for me.

Comment: Two comments: xlConnect has the same problem.  And more importantly, telling somebody to use a different library isn't a solution to the problem with the one being referenced. The goal here is to stay within the xlsx package.  There are other threads devoted to XLConnect.

Answer (score 0):

Restart R and, before loading the R packages, insert:

```
 options(java.parameters = "-Xmx2048m")
```

or

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8000m")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use gc() inside the loop if you are writing row by row. gc() stands for garbage collection. gc() can be used in any case of memory issue.

Answer (score -1):

I was having issues with `write.xlsx()` rather than reading.... but then realised that I had accidentally been running 32bit R. Swapping it out to 64bit has fixed the issue.