# Import multiple excel sheets using openxlsx

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to import a large xlsx file into R that has many sheets of data. I was attempting to do this through `XLConnect`, but java memory problems (such as those described [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937640/handling-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-when-writing-to-excel-from-r) have prevented this technique from being successful.)

Instead, I am trying to use the `openxlsx` package, which I have read works much faster and avoids Java altogether. But is there a way to use its `read.xlsx` function within a loop to read in all of the sheets into separate dataframes? The technique I was using with the other package is no longer valid bc commands like `loadWorkbook()` and `getSheets()` can no longer be used.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing nothing more than perusing the documentation for **openxlsx** quickly leads one to the function `sheets()`, which it states is deprecated in place of `names()` which returns the names of all the worksheets in a workbook. You can then iterate over them in a simple `for` loop.

I'm not sure why you say that `loadWorkbook` cannot be used. Again, the documentation clearly shows a function in **openxlsx** by that name that does roughly the same thing as in **XLConnect**, although it's arguments are slightly different.

You can also look into the **[readxl](https://github.com/hadley/readxl)** package, which also does not have a Java dependency.

Comment: Okay thank you. Apologies, sloppy of me to not notice the similar command in openxlsx. I was referring strictly to the XLConnect functions.

Answer (score 8):

I think the `getSheetNames()` function is the right function to use.  It will give you a vector of the worksheet names in a file. Then you can loop over this list to read in a list of data.frames.

```
read_all_sheets = function(xlsxFile, ...) {
  sheet_names = openxlsx::getSheetNames(xlsxFile)
  sheet_list = as.list(rep(NA, length(sheet_names)))
  names(sheet_list) = sheet_names
  for (sn in sheet_names) {
    sheet_list[[sn]] = openxlsx::read.xlsx(xlsxFile, sheet=sn, ...)
  }
  return(sheet_list)
}

read_all_sheets(myxlsxFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

'sapply' also can be used.

```
read_all_sheets = function(xlsxFile, ...) {
  sheet_names = openxlsx::getSheetNames(xlsxFile)
  sheet_list = sapply(sheet_names, function(sn){openxlsx::read.xlsx(xlsxFile, sheet=sn, ...)}, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
 return(sheet_list)
}
```

Comment: I like the compactness of this solution!