# read.xlsx cannot find Excel file

Tags: r, excel, openxls

I want to read a bunch of excel files all located in the same directory and store them in different sheets in a consolidated Excel file.

I initially tried using `XLConnect` but kept getting the error `GC overhead limit exceeded`. I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937640/handling-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-when-writing-to-excel-from-r) which says that it is a common problem with Java based Excel handling packages such as `XLConnect` and `xlsx`. I tried the memory management trick suggested there, but it did not work. One of the comments in one of the comments on the accepted answers suggested using `openxls` as it based on `RCpp` and hence avoid this particular problem.

My current code is as follows:

```
library(openxlsx)
mnth="January"
files <- list.files(path="./Original Files", pattern=mnth, full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)  #pattern match as multiple files are from the same month
# Read them into a list and write to sheet
wb <- createWorkbook()
lapply(files, function(x){
  print(x)
  xlFile<-read.xlsx(xlsxFile = x, sheet = 1, startRow = 2, colNames = T)  #Also tried
  str(xlFile)
  #Create a sheet in the new Excel file called Consolidated.xlsx with the month name
  #Append current data in sheet
})
```

The problem I am getting is the error: `Error in read.xlsx.default(xlsxFile = x, sheet = 1, startRow = 2, colNames = T) : openxlsx can not read .xls or .xlm files!`

I have ensured that `files` variable contains all the files of interest (Ex: January 2015.xls, January 2016.xls, etc). I have also ensured that the path to the file is correct and the Excel files actually exists there.

I have left the writing to Excel as skeleton code as I need to solve the problem with reading the files first.

In case it helps, here is the code attempt with `XLConnect`

```
library(XLConnect)

setwd("D:/something/something")
mnth="January"
files <- list.files(path="./Original Files", pattern=mnth, full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
# Read them into a list
df.list = lapply(files, readWorksheetFromFile, sheet=1, startRow=2)
#combine them into a single data frame and write to disk:
df = do.call(rbind, df.list)
rm(df.list)
outputFileName<-"Consolidated.xlsx"
# Load workbook (create if not existing)
wb <- loadWorkbook(outputFileName, create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, name = mnth)
writeWorksheet(wb,df,sheet = mnth)
#write.xlsx2(df, outputFileName, sheetName = mnth, col.names = T, row.names = F, append = TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb)

rm(df)
gc()
```

Comment: I'm very confused. You are lising files from `files <- list.files(path="./Original Files", ...)` but then are trying to open those file names with `xlsxFile <- system.file(x, package = "openxlsx")`. The `system.file` function opens files included with package distributions which does not seem to be what you are trying to do. I think you are just using a bad path.

Comment: I also tried using `xlFile<-read.xlsx(xlsxFile = x, sheet = 1, startRow = 2, colNames = T) `. I will update the question with the error I got with that.

Comment: The new error message seems pretty clear. The `openxlsx` package cannot read old-style `xls` files; it only reads `xlsx` files.

Comment: Thanks! Can you add that as an answer? I just assumed that since the `xlsx` package read both, so can `openxlsx`.