# How do I import a big xlsx file as workbook to read the cell color?

Tags: r, excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to import an xlsx worksheet for which I need to read the cell color.
I already read this post ( [Using R to read out excel-colorinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982344/using-r-to-read-out-excel-colorinfo?rq=1)) but I can't import the Excel file as workbook, which I understood would be a requirement to then read the cell color.

It is an xlsx file with many sheets, some of which contain thousands of rows and many columns.

The problem is that when I try

`library(XLConnect) options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1024m") wb <- loadWorkbook("My_file.xlsx")`

After a minute I get the following error

`Error: OutOfMemoryError (Java): Java heap space`

I also tried what is suggested in this post ([Importing a big xlsx file into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147884/importing-a-big-xlsx-file-into-r)), but it did not seem to work either and I can not use a simple  `read.xlsx` function because I need a WorkBook format to read the cell colors.

I also tried to copy paste the sheet I am interested in another Excel-file and then read that. Since it was a smaller file, I hoped it worked. But I got another error:

`wb <- loadWorkbook("test_wb.xlsx", create = F) Error: NoSuchMethodError (Java): org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType.getCode()S`

Any suggestion from your side?

Comment: See if this helps - [Using R to read out excel-colorinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982344/using-r-to-read-out-excel-colorinfo?rq=1).

Comment: do you have a  recent version of a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) installed? XLConnect depends on that.

Comment: Also, 1 gigabyte of heap space might not be sufficient. Try something along `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx4g")`

Comment: I do a lot of work with Excel and R. Honestly, you might want to consider fixing the problem in the workbook. Just create a dummy column (or columns) with a user defined function to pull out the color (`rng.Interior.Color` or something). You can then read that with one of the R packages not dependent on Java (`openxlsx` or `readxl`, for example). Color as data is really not ideal in Excel.

Comment: While I second the suggestion to fix it in the workbook, it is probably better to work with Excel files through the COM interface then through XLConnect.  Check out the package RDOCMClient.

Comment: @Janhoo how do I check which version of JRE I have? Thanks!

Comment: @Janhoo I tried to use more heap space, but it still returns the same error.

Comment: @Peter , Version check is explained  here: https://www.java.com/de/download/help/version_manual.xml. just install the lastest version.

Comment: Solved by adding `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8000m")` BEFORE loading my library(xlsx). Thanks to everybody!