# Search in excel workbook with R

Tags: r, xlconnect

How to search within excel workbook programmatically using R?

Say I want to locate string "foo" and return all the cell addresses (row, col, worksheet name) where the text resides.

Is there any convenience function, instead of writing own script using `xlsx::read.xlsx` or `XLConnect::readWorksheet` ?

To give a little background, I want to extract only specific regions, which I need to specify somehow.

Extracting specific regions is supported by both `read*` functions mentioned above, however they require as input the row and column indices, whereas what I know beforehand are only some keywords (representing table column headings). Example: I know there will be data about `"exposure"` or `"weight"` organized as column region with the said heading, but don't know exactly where, so want to auto-detect and extract that.

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this? Either import the data into R or use Excel/VBA facilities.

Comment: The normal way would be to import the data and then do your search. Or search the data in Excel and import what you need.

Comment: So, why can't you read-in all the data and subset? Excel sheets can hardly become so big that you run into RAM restrictions.

Comment: @Roland just asking whether such convenience function already exists. If not, I can first [convert all the sheets into giant R list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945687/how-to-read-all-worksheets-in-an-excel-workbook-into-an-r-list-with-data-frame-e?rq=1) and then [search within the list using e.g. `rlist::equal` (which btw supports fuzzy match too)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlist/vignettes/Searching.html)