# how to read Excel sheet's tab names in R?

Tags: r, excel, readxl

How can one load an Excel file to R with all its tab names? I am using the `readxl` package currently for reading Excel but can't figure out how to save its tab names?  E.g.,

```
abc = read_excel("Saudi Diapers.xlsx", 1, col_names = T)
```

Here I have specified sheet no. 1 to be read by R, but how to retrieve its name also?

Comment: Also similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945687/how-to-read-all-worksheets-in-an-excel-workbook-into-an-r-list-with-data-frame-e.  I don't think `readxl` supports getting the sheet name, but it looks like `XLConnect` does.

Comment: it does support it: ´excel_sheets("Saudi Diapers.xlsx")´

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I wanted