# Import tabbed spreadsheet into list in R

Tags: r, readxl

My data exists as a tabbed spreadsheet, and I'm trying to write a script to import it.

```
library(readxl)
oput <- 0

tabnames <- excel_sheets("dataset.xlsx")

for(x in seq_along(tabnames)){
    assign(tabnames[x], read_excel("dataset.xlsx", sheet = tabnames[x], col_names = TRUE)
}
```

This works, giving me multiple datasheets in the environment:

- tab1
- tab2
  ...

What I would like to do is have these outputs as items in a list:

```
>oput
$tab1
[1] data1
$tab2
[1] data2
...
```

But I can't get this working properly

```
assign(oput[[x]],  read_excel("dataset.xlsx", sheet = tabnames[x], col_names = TRUE)
```

and

```
assign(oput$x,  read_excel("dataset.xlsx", sheet = tabnames[x], col_names = TRUE)
```

both give:

```
Error in assign(oput[[x]], read_excel("dataset.xlsx",  : 
invalid first argument
```

It's obviously an error on my part in identifying the sheetname variable.

What's the correct way of doing this, please?

Comment: did you try `lapply()`?

Comment: a couple of issues with that: - 1) how would i pass the arguments from lapply() to the read_excel command?  - ie  `lapply(oput, read_excel("datasheet.xlsx", sheet = ???, col_names = TRUE))`  and 2) i'm trying to dynamically generate the sheet; my plan is to lapply() transformations to the data once I've gotten them in there.

Answer (score 0):

Found previously on SO with some slightly different search terms.  Apologies for the duplicate post.

[How to read all worksheets in an Excel Workbook into an R list with data.frame elements using XLConnect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945687/how-to-read-all-worksheets-in-an-excel-workbook-into-an-r-list-with-data-frame-e)