# How to manage many inputs in renderPlot output

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new using R and I'm doing a dashboard for chart indicators. In the examples, they have only one dataset or dataframe for an app that make a few charts. My problem is that I have 4 datasets for 4 charts and I don't know how to manage in order to program the server.R script, because I didn't know what to put in the renderPlot of the output. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are packages available for importing Excel worksheets where individual sheets can be named or numbered.  After you import all the sheets you need, you can combine them in R however you need.  Here's a question that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945687/read-all-worksheets-in-an-excel-workbook-into-an-r-list-with-data-frames

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widgets.html ?

Comment: Thank You very much Ryan, but I think I didn´t explain my problem correctly. I think I will change the explanation in my question. My problem is not the import, but the renderplot in the server script of my shiny app.

Comment: Well, the `renderPlot` doesn't care how you manage your data.  You can manage your data as a static global object, a static server object, or a reactive server object. `renderPlot` just needs the final call to be a plot. So, I guess I don't understand: what difference does it make that you have four datasets?  Combine them, don't combine them; load them as static object, load them as reactive objects.