# Read all worksheets (as dataframes) from multiple Excel workbooks of different structure

Tags: r, excel, worksheet, purrr, readxl

I understand that `readxl` can be used to [read in multiple worksheets from a workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945687/read-all-worksheets-in-an-excel-workbook-into-an-r-list-with-data-frames). However, I am struggling to extend this and vectorise this across many workbooks with different sheet names and number of sheets and data therein.

I demonstrate using the [Enron spreadsheet data](https://figshare.com/articles/Enron_Spreadsheets_and_Emails/1221767) which is a bunch of .xlsx files that I downloaded.

```
head(list.files("../data/enron_spreadsheets/"), 3)

[1] "albert_meyers__1__1-25act.xlsx"                           
[2] "albert_meyers__2__1-29act.xlsx"                           
[3] "andrea_ring__10__ENRONGAS(1200).xlsx"
```

To make it manageable, we sample.

```
# Set the path to your directory of Enron spreadsheets here
enron_path <- "../data/enron_spreadsheets/"
# Set the sample size for testing here
sample_size <- 100
all_paths <- list.files(enron_path,
                    full.names = TRUE)

# For testing, look at n (sample_size) random workbooks.
set.seed(1337)
sample_paths <- sample(all_paths, sample_size)

paths <- sample_paths
```

Inspecting these workbooks and counting the number of worksheets therein reveals they have different number of sheets and contain different data.

```
# purr package
# https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/index.html
sheet_count <- purrr::map(paths, readxl::excel_sheets) %>%
  purrr::map(length) %>%
  unlist()

hist(sheet_count, main = "")
```

However, to load all the sheets in a workbook into a [list of data frames](http://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/readxl-workflows.html#iterate-over-multiple-worksheets-in-a-workbook), we need to:

- Get worksheet names as a self-named character vector (these names propagate nicely).
- Use `purrr::map()` to iterate sheet reading.

  ```
  books <-
    dplyr::data_frame(filename = basename(paths),
               path = paths,
               sheet_name = purrr::map(paths, readxl::excel_sheets)
               ) %>%  
    dplyr::mutate(id = as.character(row_number()))

    books

  # A tibble: 100 x 4
                               filename
                                  <chr>
   1  kenneth_lay__19485__Mlp_1109.xlsx
   2 kate_symes__18980__SP 15 pages.xls
   3 chris_germany__1821__newpower-purc
   4 john_griffith__15991__Forwards Det
   5   jane_tholt__13278__bid2001A.xlsx
   6 gerald_nemec__11481__EOLfieldnames
   7 stacey_white__39009__Power RT Serv
   8      eric_saibi__9766__012302.xlsx
   9 david_delainey__8083__ENA Status o
  10  daren_farmer__5035__HPLN0405.xlsx
  # ... with 90 more rows, and 3
  #   more variables: path <chr>,
  #   sheet_name <list>, id <chr>
  ```

Here we have one row per workbook in `books` with the workbook's worksheet names stored in a list column. We want one row per worksheet with the data contents of the worksheet stored in a list column so that we can add extra features based on the worksheets data (the worksheet is the experimental unit). The problem is it doesn't vectorise as expected, am I  missing something?

This errors...

```
sheets <-
  tibble::tibble("sheet_name" = unlist(books$sheet_name),
                 "path" = rep(paths,
                              times = unlist(
                                purrr::map_int(books$sheet_name, length))
                              ),
                 "filename" = basename(path),
                 "sheet_data" = tibble::lst(
                   readxl::read_excel(path = path[], 
                                      sheet = sheet_name[])
                   )
             ) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(id = as.character(row_number()))

Error in switch(ext, xls = "xls", xlsx = "xlsx", xlsm = "xlsx", if (nzchar(ext)) { : 
  EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

The code works when not passed a vector for workbook path and sheet name, but obviously the data is not from the correct worksheet in this example below:

```
sheets <-
  tibble::tibble("sheet_name" = unlist(books$sheet_name),
                 "path" = rep(paths,
                              times = unlist(
                                purrr::map_int(books$sheet_name, length))
                              ),
                 "filename" = basename(path),
                 "sheet_data" = tibble::lst(
                   readxl::read_excel(path = path[1], 
                                      sheet = sheet_name[1])
                   )
             ) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(id = as.character(row_number()))

dplyr::glimpse(sheets)

Observations: 313
Variables: 5
$ sheet_name <chr> "MLP's", "DJ SP15", "newpower-p...
$ path       <chr> "../data/enron_spreadsheets//ke...
$ filename   <chr> "kenneth_lay__19485__Mlp_1109.x...
$ sheet_data <list> [<# A tibble: 57 x 46,        ...
$ id         <chr> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "...
```

How do I read in the data from many worksheets in many workbooks into a list column in a tibble?

I'm new to reading in messy spreadsheets and using `purrr` any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mention the `purrr` package, some other tidyverse packages are worth considering.

- [`dplyr`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/)  for `mutate()`, when applying `purrr::map()` to a column of a data frame and storing the result as list-column.
- [`tidyr`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) for `unnest()`, which expands a list-column so that each row inside a list-column becomes a row in the overall data frame.
- [`tibble`](http://tibble.tidyverse.org/) for nicely printed nested data frames

Sample files are needed to demonstrate.  This code uses the [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=openxlsx) package to create one file containing two sheets (the built-in `iris` and `mtcars` datasets), and another file containing three sheets (adding the built-in `attitude` dataset).

```r
library(openxlsx)

# Create two spreadsheet files, with different numbers of worksheets
write.xlsx(list(iris, mtcars, attitude), "three_sheets.xlsx")
write.xlsx(list(iris, mtcars),           "two_sheets.xlsx")
```

Now a solution.

First, list the filenames, which will passed to `readxl::excel_sheets()` for the names of the sheets within each file, and  `readxl::read_excel()` to import the data itself.

```r
(paths <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx"))
#> [1] "three_sheets.xlsx" "two_sheets.xlsx"

(x <- tibble::data_frame(path = paths))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   path             
#>   <chr>            
#> 1 three_sheets.xlsx
#> 2 two_sheets.xlsx
```

'Map' the `readxl::excel_sheets()` function over each of the file paths, and store the results in a new list-column.  Each row of the `sheet_name` column is a vector of sheet names.  As expected, the first one has three sheet names, while the second has two.

```r
(x <- dplyr::mutate(x, sheet_name = purrr::map(path, readxl::excel_sheets)))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   path              sheet_name
#>   <chr>             <list>    
#> 1 three_sheets.xlsx <chr [3]> 
#> 2 two_sheets.xlsx   <chr [2]>
```

We need to pass each filename and each sheet name into `readxl::read_excel(path=, sheet=)`, so the next step is to have a data frame where each row gives a path and one sheet name.  This is done using `tidyr::unnest()`.

```r
(x <- tidyr::unnest(x))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   path              sheet_name
#>   <chr>             <chr>     
#> 1 three_sheets.xlsx Sheet 1   
#> 2 three_sheets.xlsx Sheet 2   
#> 3 three_sheets.xlsx Sheet 3   
#> 4 two_sheets.xlsx   Sheet 1   
#> 5 two_sheets.xlsx   Sheet 2
```

Now each path and sheet name can be passed into `readxl::read_excel()`, using  `purrr::map2()` rather than `purrr::map()` because we pass two arguments rather than one.

```r
(x <- dplyr::mutate(x, data = purrr::map2(path, sheet_name,
                                          ~ readxl::read_excel(.x, .y))))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   path              sheet_name data              
#>   <chr>             <chr>      <list>            
#> 1 three_sheets.xlsx Sheet 1    <tibble [150 × 5]>
#> 2 three_sheets.xlsx Sheet 2    <tibble [32 × 11]>
#> 3 three_sheets.xlsx Sheet 3    <tibble [30 × 7]> 
#> 4 two_sheets.xlsx   Sheet 1    <tibble [150 × 5]>
#> 5 two_sheets.xlsx   Sheet 2    <tibble [32 × 11]>
```

Now each dataset is in a separate row of the `data` column.  We can look at just one of the datasets by subsetting that column.

```r
x$data[3]
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 30 x 7
#>    rating complaints privileges learning raises critical advance
#>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1   43.0       51.0       30.0     39.0   61.0     92.0    45.0
#>  2   63.0       64.0       51.0     54.0   63.0     73.0    47.0
#>  3   71.0       70.0       68.0     69.0   76.0     86.0    48.0
#>  4   61.0       63.0       45.0     47.0   54.0     84.0    35.0
#>  5   81.0       78.0       56.0     66.0   71.0     83.0    47.0
#>  6   43.0       55.0       49.0     44.0   54.0     49.0    34.0
#>  7   58.0       67.0       42.0     56.0   66.0     68.0    35.0
#>  8   71.0       75.0       50.0     55.0   70.0     66.0    41.0
#>  9   72.0       82.0       72.0     67.0   71.0     83.0    31.0
#> 10   67.0       61.0       45.0     47.0   62.0     80.0    41.0
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

Comment: This method works for your example @nacnudus but due to a putative [bug](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/408) in readxl, it does not work for reading in all the Enron workbooks' worksheets. This may be due to some worksheets being empty / containing no data.

Comment: The real bug is probably in some xls-to-xlsx conversion tool, so we'll probably never know.  The issue can be tracked here https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/408.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this an it worked fine for one workbook.

```
library(readxl)    
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename) {
    sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
    x <-    lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
    names(x) <- sheets
    x
}
```

This could be called with:

```
mysheets <- read_excel_allsheets("foo.xls")
```

Note, it is for xls and xlsx; it will not work for xlsb files.