# To know efficient method of making a list of lists of Workbooks and sheets

Tags: r

I have sheets in a Workbook and then n number of Workbooks. These Workbooks are in a folder and I need to perform operations on sheets separately as data been incoherent.

*I'm using*

```
excelFiles <- list.files(path = path, pattern = '.*\\.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)
data_list <- import_list(excelFiles)
```

But this code makes a list of 'n' number of Workbooks and opens the 1st sheet on using `data_list[[1]] and data_list[1]`

**What I need is**  sheets as df to perform functions and logic to go through to get them from folders.

Edit: `rio` is used for `import_list`.

Comment: This question is a potential duplicate. Reference [Read all worksheets in an Excel workbook into an R list with data.frames
r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945687/read-all-worksheets-in-an-excel-workbook-into-an-r-list-with-data-frames).

Comment: where is the function `import_list()` from?

Comment: Is this using the Rio library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently when we pass a list of file names that's what happens, while if we pass only a single file name it works fine. So, instead you may use

```
library(rio)
data_list <- lapply(excelFiles, import_list)
```

Then `data_list` is a list of elements corresponding to workbooks, and where each element is again a list of elements corresponding to sheets. So, for instance, `data_list[[1]][[2]]` is 1st workbook, 2nd sheet. In case you want only a list of sheets, then you may use

```
sheets <- unlist(data_list, recursive = FALSE)
```

where now `sheets[[34]]` is 34th sheet corresponding to who knows which workbook.

Comment: Still `Soft <- data_list[[1]]` doesn't give a sheet. I have to use `Soft1 <- Soft[[1]]` to make Soft1 a data frame.