# using R to collate and visualize monthly data held in different excel sheets

Tags: r, trend, visualize

How do i collate monthly data held in different excel sheets in R? i want to import only a few sheets of a workbook. and then use R to aggregate and visualize monthly trend?

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't have any example of datasets, but I guess you are trying to ask below set of things:

Task1. Reading data from various sheets of an excel.
Task2. Collate the data in one data frame say masterdata
Task3. draw some plots for required fields

Apporch: you can import multiple sheets into a list and then combine list to get masterData, A brief discussion is given in the existing question refer link below:

[Read all worksheets in an Excel workbook into an R list with data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945687/read-all-worksheets-in-an-excel-workbook-into-an-r-list-with-data-frames)