# How to skip empty rows while reading multiple tabs in R?

Tags: r, excel, readxl

I am trying to read an excel file with multiple tabs. For that, I use the code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69765502/9510022).
The problem is that each tab has a different number of empty rows before the actual data begins. For example, the first tab has two empty rows, the second tab has three empty rows, and so on.

Normally, I would use the parameter `skip` in the `read_excel` function to indicate the number of empty lines to skip. But how do I do that for multiple tabs with different numbers of rows to skip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps the easiest solution would be to read it as it is then remove rows, i.e. yourdata <- yourdata[!is.na(yourdata$columname),] ; this would work if you don't expect any NA's in a particular column, like id. If you have data gaps everywhere you can test for all NAs in multiple columns - let me know if that's what you need.

Comment: Yes, this should work, thank you! I was just wondering if there is an already implemented and more elegant way to do that, but this approach is fine too, I guess

Comment: Sorry, I wondered the same thing just now and apparently if you use read.xls function you can add "blank.lines.skip=TRUE" parameter for that

Comment: I somehow cannot make it work:( I get `Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument`, even though the usual `readxl::read_excel` works perfectly well

Comment: yeah, sorry, should have made it more obvious - a different package for reading excel: gdata

Comment: Yeah, I did import it. This error is related to something else

Comment: I think you just specify the file path without the file argument, i.e. or use "df1 <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = xlsxFile, sheet = 1, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)...", so from docs is says xlsxFile rather than file