# R Concatenate Columns from Excel file based on sheet name and Column's name

Tags: r, import, tidyverse, data-wrangling, readxl

Hello Guys I have an excel file that has multiple `sheetnames` and these sheet names dont always have the same structure I wanna be able to read the excel file, read only some specifics sheets, select some specific columns and then create a concatenated table I have the following excel file:

`File_Mother.xlsx` it has 5 sheets but we would only need those sheets that have the pattern "inning_19" at the beginning of their names so "inning_195" and "inning_1988" will be of interest if they exist within the excel file,  extract the columns `ID_MATCH` and `SET_GAME` along with all other columns that starts with the pattern "`id_complete_game_on`" and finally create a column that will let me know the sheet name that this info was taken from when we `bind` vertically all the data selected. for example:

From `File_Mother.xlsx` I have
sheet.name = "inning_195" with the following info

| ID_MATCH | SET_GAME | id_complete_game_on_field | id_complete_game_on_camp |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X01 | M | cleared | not cleared |  |
| X85 | Q | cleared | cleared |  |
| X89 | U | cleared | cleared |  |

From `File_Mother.xlsx` I have
sheet.name = "inning_1988" with the following info

| ID_MATCH | SET_GAME | id_complete_game_on_demand_one | id_complete_game_on_camp |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IKX01 | MR | completed | not cleared |  |
| IKX02 | DD | not completed | cleared |  |
| IKX03 | TT | draw | cleared |  |

after the desired data wrangling the output will be

| ID_MATCH | SET_GAME | id_complete_game_on_field | id_complete_game_on_camp | id_complete_game_on_demand_one | sheet name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X01 | M | cleared | not cleared | NA | inning_195 |
| X85 | Q | cleared | cleared | NA | inning_195 |
| X89 | U | cleared | cleared | NA | inning_195 |
| IKX01 | MR | NA | NA | completed | inning_1988 |
| IKX02 | DD | NA | NA | not completed | inning_1988 |
| IKX03 | TT | NA | NA | draw | inning_1988 |

Thank you guys SO MUCH I have been trying to do this all week but I have not yet gotten what I want if there is a blog or a piece of code that you think can help please post it on the comments thank you so much! I will be looking constantly to award you with the answer thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly edit [reading all sheets of excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945687/read-all-worksheets-in-an-excel-workbook-into-an-r-list-with-data-frames) by @Jeromy Anglim.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

read_excel_somesheets <- function(filename, key,tibble = FALSE) {
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
  x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X) %>% mutate(sheet_name = X))
  if(!tibble) x <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)
  names(x) <- sheets
  y <- x[grepl(key, names(x))] %>%
    reduce(full_join)
  y
}
```

Then you may try

```
read_excel_somesheets("your_path/File_Mother.xlsx", "inning_19")
```

And result is like

```
  ID_MATCH SET_GAME id_complete_game_on_field id_complete_game_on_camp  sheet_name id_complete_game_on_demand_one
1      X01        M                   cleared              not cleared  inning_195                           <NA>
2      X85        Q                   cleared                  cleared  inning_195                           <NA>
3      X89        U                   cleared                  cleared  inning_195                           <NA>
4    IKX01       MR                      <NA>              not cleared inning_1988                      completed
5    IKX02       DD                      <NA>                  cleared inning_1988                  not completed
6    IKX03       TT                      <NA>                  cleared inning_1988                           draw
```

Comment: This is incredible thank you so much! What would you recommend me in order to learn more about importing files ans sheets from Excel into R?

Comment: @R_Student You may just google it on your purpose. There are lots of contents.